# What is the best way to perform a null check WITHOUT the NullPointerException being thrown?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So I know I MAY have a null List (ArrayList, specifically). Now a simple check for it like that actually throws a NullPointerException when I'm already checking for it. This one has me stumped since I've always used it successfully but I'm sure I'm missing something:

```
public class MyPost {

private int id;

private List<Label> labels;

public MyPost(int id){ this.id = id }

//getter setters for both plus this added method:

public void addLabel(Label aLabel)
  {
     if(labels == null)
       labels = new ArrayList<Label>();

     labels.add(aLabel);
  }

}
```

Now in another part of my code I am iterating over the list of ID's sent by the client. For simplicity assume that a loop variable 'i' is supplying the ids

```
MyPost aPost = new MyPost(i);
```

In my logic I may or may not add labels to the post. So at the end before proceeding I check for existence of labels like that:

```
if(aPost.getLabels()!=null)
   //process labels
```

Now this throws a null pointer exception if nothing was ever added to the list of labels! But that's exactly what I want to check for and am still getting an NPE!!!

I know aPost.getLabels() IS null if nothing is ever added to it. But the comparison seems to fail and throw an NPE. How to address this issue? Just has me stumped!

**UPDATE:**
Here is the get label code. Just a trivial getter...

```
public List<Label> getLabels() { return labels;}
```

We noticed something that we overlooked before. I'm sure java used to "short circuit" it's if-conditions i.e., in an OR condition if the first condition evaluated to true it wouldn't check the second one (similar short-circuiting for AND if the first condition evaluated to false). I am not entirely sure if that is the cause but here's the if-clause:

```
if(aPost.getLabels()!=null || !aPost.getLabels().isEmpty())
//process labels
```

If the list is indeed null short-circuiting shouldn't evaluate the second condition, correct?? It seems that may be the cause, but we are still testing it out. Just a hunch for now...

Comment: Show us the `getLabels()` code.

Comment: Post your getLabels() method and your NPE if you can

Comment: If that simple comparison throws NPE, maybe its better for you to check whether aPost is null or not. I think, the NPE thrown before the comparison.

Comment: @Nupul: have you read the correct answers given? They are telling you that aPost is null. I know you state that it's not, but have you done a check? A simple `System.out.println("aPost is null: " + (aPost == null));` will do just before the line throwing the NPE.

Comment: @Hovercraft: replied to your comment below. Yes I've added the check. It's always printed as not null :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general the first thing you do when you debug an NPE is to examine the stack trace closely and identify the exact line it is thrown from.

The next step is to check all the values that are **on the left side** of a dereferencing operator (`.`) on that line. Another source of NPEs is the new flavour of `for` loops, and the third  one is auto-unboxing, As far as I know, there are no other constructs that inherently throw an NPE, although of course there can always be code that throws it explicitly.

All this means that without the stack trace and the complete code we can only guess too.

(Alternatively, if you're using an IDE you can simply set an exception breakpoint and examine the runtime values of your variables at the moment the NPE is being thrown. But you should be able to find an NPE by offline analysis of the code and the stack trace. It's an important skill.)

**Update**: Looking at the updated question it's obvious that the if statement is wrong. It should read:

```
if(aPost.getLabels()!=null && !aPost.getLabels().isEmpty())
//process labels
```

OR isn't the correct operation there, since you want `aPost.getLabels()` to be not null AND not to be empty. Java does indeed stop boolean expression evaluation as soon as the value is known, but in your original expression this wasn't the case if `aPost.getLabels()` was null.

Comment: aPost is NOT null at all. It's actually created before proceeding with the code. But it seems there is a place in the code where the if-check is an OR `if(aPost.getLabels()!=null || !aPost.getLabels().isEmpty())` It seems that the condition is NOT short circuiting but trying to evaluate both and hence the NPE...but I'm not totally sure on this one as yet and am in the process of evaluating...have updated my OP

Comment: Well, if you post a different code to what you actually have, don't be surprised if you don't get the correct answer. Looking at the updated version I can see that you simply got the wrong operation. It should be `&&` and not `||`. Java shortcircuiting works correctly.

Comment: Hmmm...seems to make sense ~(A || B) = ~A && ~B Guess we totally overlooked the basic demorgan's law! Still testing it out though...will get back

Comment: @Nupul: you can't say that aPost is NOT null unless you check it. Please put in a line of code that checks this just before where you see the NPE, and then tell us what you get.

Comment: @Hovercraft: I did add the line `if(aPost==null) s.o.p("aPost NULL") else s.o.p("aPost NOT NULL")` The output is always NOT NULL

Comment: @biziclop: This may sound naive but I'm getting a bit confused - if the if-clause does have an OR instead of the AND as you suggest it seems this scenario is the cause of the NPE - where `getLabels()` is indeed NULL. Since the `null!=null` comparison will fail and it'll try and evaluate the `...isEmpty()` part, correct?

Comment: @Nupul This is 100% correct, yes. But the general part of my answer is what you should try to remember, because if you follow the instructions, you'll be able to hunt down NPEs in no time.

Comment: @biziclop: Aye Aye Sir! Burned to memory! FYI - I guess we had the same logical bug at quite a few places in code in different modules but they never threw an NPE, as yet :) Thanks a ton for all the help!

Comment: I've just thought of one more thing that might help you weed out errors like this before they start to cause problems: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

A better way to code it would be to always initialise the array, and instead of null checking simply iterate over the list, which in the empty case would do nothing because it's empty (not null).

```
public class MyPost {
    private int id;
    private List<Label> labels = new ArrayList<Label>;
    public MyPost(int id){ this.id = id }

    //getter setters for both plus this added method:
    public void addLabel(Label aLabel) {
        labels.add(aLabel);
    }
}

// then later...
public void someProcessing() {
    for (Label label: labels) {
        // process label here
    }
}
```

Now you no longer have a NPE, and you're not having to have nasty looking null checking code, you simply rely on the fact an empty list won't iterate.

Alternatively (as I say in my comments) if you have to lazy instantiate the List, do that but always return a valid List object that can be iterated over, by changing the getLabels() to

```
public List<Label> getLabels() {
    return labels == null ? Collections.emptyList() : labels
}
```

This means that no method that calls getLabels() ever need check for a null object, they can simply iterate over the returned object, which is presumably what you'll end up doing to the list eventually. This really does improve code reliability, and readability. I have to review a lot of code that has this belt and bracers approach of always checking for nulls before accessing objects, which could all be cleaned up by ensuring the returned object acts as its name sake instead of potentially being null.

EDIT: remove the section about the getLabels() after OP updated post about the actual `if` statement used, and added the comments about making the List act as a List.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's just not true.

Comment: @Mark: That is how one would do lazy loading. And if it is indeed null the null check would catch it...the issue is that it isn't being caught

Comment: @biziclop what isn't true? the point of my post is that you don't need any null checks if you give it an empty array to start with, and I think it looks cleaner to simply `for()` over the array than putting an `if( a!=null && a.b.isEmpty())` condition that is simply not needed anymore.

Comment: @nupul - i understand lazy loading, and again as I say, i'm showing how the OP's code can be written without any null checks that will never throw a NPE. The iteration of the loop will skip if there are no labels in the array, which to me is a preferred style to null checks.

Comment: @Mark Fisher Essentially the part that you deleted. :) Anyway, sometimes initialising collections from the constructor is better and sometimes it isn't. But unless you're using a system that enforces pre- and post-conditions, your code has to be able to handle null input.

Comment: @biziclop I see! Your extra code made me realise my mistake. I would still argue it's better to make your `List` objects act as `List`s, and so that you don't have to do null checks in the code that uses them. If you do need to lazy load it (e.g. for performance), then a better way than writing `if (myList != null ...)` would be to change the getter to something like `return labels == null ? Collections.emptyList() : labels;` so everyone who uses the `getLabels()` never has to check for null. As I see it, the solutions here are fine, but the address the symptoms not the cause.

Comment: @biziclop I've updated my answer to reflect what is IMHO a better way of ensuring you don't fall into the trap of constantly writing null checks in code. For the most part (especially if it's your class you're accessing) you don't need them, and the code will benefit for it.

Comment: @biziclop: You should check for nulls at the boundaries of your system, because you can't ensure non-nullity of values coming from foreign code. But there's no point checking everything in sight. That's simply unnecessary code, and as such, bad programming.

Comment: @Tom Anderson In OOP every class is a boundary. Being able to handle null input doesn't necessarily mean explicitly checking it every time though, as often the only thing you could do is throw another exception. Not to mention that there are more effective and less verbose ways of checking preconditions than sticking an if statement in. What you should never do is take a non-null value for granted when it isn't, that **is** bad programming.

Comment: @biziclop: "In OOP every class is a boundary": but of varying strength. Two classes which are collaborators do not have a strong boundary between them. Classes which are part of different modules have a stronger boundary. "What you should never do is take a non-null value for granted when it isn't" - absolutely true. But sometimes, it is!

Answer (score 1):

You are actually missing something, although you are very close to what you want :

a null pointer exception is thrown in an expression of the form

```
A.method()

A.field
```

if A is null.  This means that in a statement like

```
a.b.c.d.e().f.g
```

a null pointer exception is thrown if either a is null or a.b is null, or a.b.c is null, and so on : something at the left hand side of a dot is null.

So in you example, if you get an exception when doing

```
if(aPost.getLabels()!=null)
```

the only solution is that aPost is null. Nothing else.

And actually you are right, to know if something is null, it's good to compare it to null using equal sign (==)

Add the following to your code :

```
if( aPost == null )
   System.out.println( "Oh, aPost is null itself and my bug is not related to its fields being null." );
```

Regards,
 Stéphane